# Bild Union for each element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm searching for an operator (replace the ?), to solve this equation:

$$ M ? \{ K, L \} = \{ M \cup K, M \cup L \} $$

M, K, L are sets.

Does something like this exist?

(Actually $\{ K, L \}$ is a power set, but I think this doesn't matter.)

---

To clarify my question: I'm searching for a short way to write:

$$ \{a\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{a, b, c\} $$

So $M = \{a\}$ and $K, L$ are wildcards for elements from $\mathcal{P}(b, c)$

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. I don't think there's a standard symbol for that operator, but I'm reasonably certain that, under ZF, if $\{K,L\}$ is a set then $\{M\cup K, M\cup L\}$ is a set (just use the axiom of replacement).

Comment: What do you mean by saying that $\{ K, L \}$ is a power set, and why don't you think this matters? It could matter a lot: if $\{ K, L \}$ is a power set with only two elements, then that tells you a lot about the sets $K$ and $L$.

Comment: @Billy I hope my update helps you

Comment: @CliveNewstead I'm not about to proof anything

Comment: If you're just looking for some shorthand notation: I don't think it exists in general. But there's nothing stopping you making it up for the benefit of a reader. Tell your reader that you're going to give this special operation the name $*$, then just call it that.

Comment: @Billy I feared that :D I'm unsure if the creation of a new symbol is to much effort for my purposes (but I thought of something like a combination of $\cup$ and $\times$, but sadly LaTeX only provides $\uplus$) Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Billy You don't even need replacement for that. Just the axiom of pairing and union.

Comment: a in X subset { a,b,c}

Comment: @WilliamElliot I haven't seen a notation like this. Is this common? $a \in X \subseteq \{ a, b, c \}$

Comment: @WilliamElliot actually I off course can write $\{ X \subseteq \{a, b, c\} | a  \in X \}$, but this isn't really shorter